# Implement an interpreter in Ocaml

Tags: ocaml, interpreter, caml

i'm trying to write an interpreter in Ocaml, i have defined the syntax already and the semantic for the most of the operations.
I'm trying to implement two more operations:

**Ntimes**: this has two argouments, an Integer and a function. Ntimes has to apply the function n times.

**Pipe**: this is the same has the pipe in the linux bash.

example of Ntimes:

```
Ntimes(Int(4),f);;
```

example of Pipe:

```
Pipe(f1,(f2,(f3,(f4,(f5,Nil)))));;
```

The interpeter that i have is this:

**SYNTAX**

```
type ide = string;;

    type operator = Plus | Minus | Mul | Div | And | Or | Eq;;

    type exp = Int of int
             | Bool of bool
             | Den of string
             | Op of exp * operator * exp
             | Let of ide * exp * exp
             | Fun of ide * exp
             | Apply of exp * exp
             | Ifz of exp * exp * exp
             | Etup of tuple
             | Pipe of tuple
             | ManyTimes of int * exp
                and tuple = Nil | Seq of exp * tuple;;



type dexp = Dint of int | Dbool of bool | Dstring of string | Unbound | Dtuple of dexp list | Funval of efun and efun = ide * exp * dexp env ;;
```

**RUN-TIME SUPPORT**

```
let rec eval ((e: exp), (r:dexp env)) = match e with
         Int i -> Dint i
       | Bool i -> Dbool i
       .
       .
       .
       .
       | Etup e1 -> let v = (evalList e1 r) in Dtuple v
       | Apply(e1, e2) -> (match eval(e1, r) with
                | Funval(i, a, r1) -> eval(a, bind(r1, i, eval(e2, r)))
                | _ -> failwith("no funct in apply"))
       | NTimes(i,e) -> *I have no idea*
       | Pipe(e) -> * I have no idea*
       ;;
```

Thanks for the any help that you will give me!

Comment: Why not use a simple `list` instead of those "`tuple`s"?

Comment: Try to rewrite the `NTimes`/`Pipe` into `Apply`s, and then just call `eval` on that.

Comment: i'm not using a `list` because i must implement it with `tuple`. A tuple is : a tuple is a sequence of elements that can be of differents types. `let p2 = eval(Let("t",Etup(Seq(Int 3, Seq(Int 33, Seq(Bool true,Nil)))),Den "t"), emptyenv Unbound) in p2;;` @Bergi

Comment: Yeah, still you should realise that they form a list structure and you can (should) use structural recursion on it. Or you convert it to a `exp list` if that simplifies it for you.

Comment: I'm actually valuating the tuple expression into a list `evalList el r = match el with 
           Nil -> []
         | Seq (e1,el1) -> (eval(e1,r))::(evalList el1 r)` If this is what you mean.

Comment: Yes, so you have at least *some* idea. Now what do you need to do with that list? What does "pipe" do in the bash?

Comment: Isn't the point of your homework to do it yourself?

Comment: I thought at this code in eval:  `| Pipe(e) -> let tup = eval(e,r) in
       eval(tup, r)` this product a list of Apply, and then I evaluate this list, but i have a type error. @Bergi

Comment: @PatJ Actually the homework was to write the whole interpreter, i just miss these 2 operations. I'm not asking for the code but i'm just looking for some ideas.

Comment: `Pipe` does not contain an expression `e` that you can `eval`, it contains a list (tuple). You need to get the list from `e`, then `eval` each element, then apply them in order (or you build nested `Apply`s from the tuples and then `eval` that expression).

Comment: I guess that ManyTimes ≡ Ntimes but then Ntimes(Int(4),f) is not sound.  What is supposed to return Ntimes(4, Int(2))?

Comment: Yes ManyTimes is equivalent of Ntimes. The argoument of Ntimes is a function and an Integer. @ChriS

Comment: So i came up with a solution, i modified the syntax of `Pipe` to be `Pipe of tuple * exp` , the idea here is to use the `exp` for the parameter of the first function that will be evaluated, then i do `Pipe(f,par) -> let rec crealista a = match a with 
        | Nil -> par
        | Seq(e1,el1) -> Apply(e1,crealista(el1))
        in let lista = crealista(f) in eval (lista,r)`  This creates a nested Apply sequence and then evaluates it as you hinted me @Bergi , i was wondering if it can be done without modifying the Syntax

Comment: I'm not sure what a "pipe" does *exactly* mean in your language. One question: what does `Pipe(Nil)` mean? I can see three more or less reasonable ways: 1) it's evaluated left-to-right and the first element in the sequence is the starting argument value 2) it's evaluated right-to-left and the last element is the starting value. (In those cases, empty pipes make no sense). 3) a pipe actually produces another function  and needs to be `Apply`ed itself. Either only match `Apply(Pipe(f), par) -> crealista f`, or do something like `Pipe(f) -> Funval("x", let par = Den "x" in crealista f)`

Comment: I actually made a mistake in the Pipe example in the main post it should be something like `Pipe(f1,(f2,(f3,(f4,(f5,Par)))));;`, Regarding the `Pipe(Nil)` , we are assuming that no one will ever call Pipe with a Nil argoument but we are sure that the argoument is correct.

Comment: i have followed your hints, but i get a type error: `This expression has type 'a -> 'b
       but an expression was expected of type exp` with the code: `| Apply((Pipe(f),par))->  eval(crealista(f,par),r) and crealista f par =  match f with 
        | Nil -> par
        | Seq(e1,el1) -> Apply(e1,crealista(el1, par))` @Bergi . I don't know why..

Comment: I said "something like" as I left out your `crealista` declaration. Your snippet seems to miss a `let … in`, and `crealista` is declared with two parameters but called with tuples.

Comment: Sorry but i don't understand, why i can't use two parameters in `crealista`? @Bergi

Comment: You can, but then the call `crealista(f,par)`  should've been `crealista f par`

Comment: Thank you very much @Bergi, you helped me so much! I've managed to complete the interpreter :)